# How to do job scheduling in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, redis, cron

I have a peculiar problem. I am making a social network type application. When i create a post and put it on a schedule to post itself at the defined time (like Gmail mail scheduling), i want to have job which checks the post's  timezone and post it itself according to different country's timezone. Like when i schedule it to post at the night in US, it should show in Asian user's timelines during the day (just an approximate generalisation). How can i achieve this? Should i have a cron job running or there is a better way to do that?

Any approach which prevents adding another thing to the tech stack will be highly appreciated.

I am using nodejs, postgre, mongo, redis and RabbitMQ

Comment: https://github.com/agenda/agenda
refer this

Comment: @vicky i know this comes at a simple Google search. I wanted a full approach, an explanation, rather than a library.

Comment: that document is enough to explaination

Comment: @vicky not in my case. Whatever agenda can do, it can be done with cron. nothing new. I want an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I want to clarify about the CRON.
Some "pending" tasks or scripts are called "Cron Jobs". Cron jobs are great for regular actions such as backups, deleting files (for example, logs) etc.
But in other cases it's better to implement business logic in your application. Because cron jobs hard to scale with your app(run in several instance), also it must be monitored so that only one instance of the cron is always running...Of course you can use k8s cron.

In your case, I would do something like this:

- store all posts in UTC time(this will help you with users in different time zones)
- add to posts information about "do not show until"
- and additional conditional where comparing "current time" and "do not show until" when you need to show all posts

Another way, you can use [rabbitmq(delayed messages)](https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/delayed-messages.html). Handle this actions in nodejs when the time is come and rabbitmq will notify nodejs about task.
This is probably the best solution, but there is one thing...now you have to use **RabbitMQ**

I think you should have a better idea which option to choose.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. Also, by cron, i didn't meant cron script, but implementing in node itself via cron module. Also, we are already using RabbitMQ :)

Comment: Koa,Agendajs,Bull and bee are alternatives to schedule a job